# Regex for selecting everything but characters between a given symbol

Tags: java, regex

What is the regex for selecting everything except the characters between a given symbol.

If the given symbol is '%' then, `<simple%name%>` should produce `<simple>`

Comment: Will the be only one `%--text--%`, or will the be multiple occurrences of the symbol?

Comment: @BlackPearl only one

Comment: No, everything except what is between the `%` characters would produce `<simple>`. You need to specify the problem more clearly and in far greater detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- % matches the character %
- . matches any character (except new line)
- *? finds the next match of a character

So the following line first finds %, then finds any other character until it finds %

```
"%.*?%"
```

So as an example:

```
String str = "<Simple%Name 1 % 1a%Foo%>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("%.*?%", ""));
```

Would produce:

```
<Simple 1a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like *"%(.*?)%"*

Here is the example i have tried considering your input string would be

> simple%name%

```
String str = "simple%name%";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("%(.*?)%", ""));
```

Output for this will be

> simple